# Flutter insert into sqlite.db

Tags: flutter, sqflite

I have an issue. The first, i have a example.db. after that i insert into `histories_table`. but it doesn't save on example.db. How to fix it? Thanks so much.

[image: example.db]

[image]

```
Future<void> insertDB(int ftsId) async {
    final db = await ConectionDB.dbPro.databaseUser;
    DateTimeHelper helper = new DateTimeHelper();
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String createdAt = helper.formatDateTime(now.toString());
    Map<String, dynamic> row = {
      'fts_main_content_id': ftsId,
      'createdAt': createdAt,
    };
    await db.insert(tableName, row);
    print(await db.query(tableName)); 
  }
```

Comment: do you pull modifed db file from your device/emulator after insert?

Comment: did it print anything in log?

Comment: @Mertus i just insert. but example.db i check it and it not change

Comment: @JohnJoe it print. but not save on example.db.

Comment: Are the records there next time you open the app?

Comment: @Mertus The records show whenever i navigator `HistoryScreen`